# .NET Authentication .NET 7 Vs .NET 8 in my simple API service

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I'm building a relatively simple .NET core web API service that does some CRUD operations on a database. I'm a bit confused about implementing authentication. It looks like in .NET 7 you have to manually define all the endpoints, but in .NET 8 they are already defined out of the box.

I want to have a simple set of endpoints for the following actions:

- login
- register
- confirm email (generate confirm email link and send via SMTP)
- reset password
- social login with google (not sure if that has anything to do with my question, but I'll mention that)

I tried implementing authentication in .NET 8 and I expected that it can all be configured, but it also comes with some other endpoints like 2fa which I don't want to use for this project. I'm also not sure how can I edit the predefined .NET 8 **register** controller because that's where I want to trigger the SMTP call to sent the confirm link.

What's the best route to take - should I define my Controllers manually or should I just use .NET 8 predefined controllers and somehow disable the ones I don't need and edit the one that I need? Is the .NET 8 out of the box package configurable enough to achieve my goals?

Comment: `should I define my Controllers manually or should I just use .NET 8 predefined controllers and somehow disable the ones I don't need and edit the one that I need?` --> that depends on whether you think the predefine APIs are able to meet your requirement, according to your description, it might be ok. Other APIs which are not required for you, you could just disable them or ignore them. And about the `generate confirm email link and send via SMTP`, this requires you to compose by yourself, because you need to have your own email system.

Comment: I found a blog might be helpful for you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-with-identity-in-dotnet-8/    and this document:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Yes it looks like they meet my requirements. Can you expand more on this part "you could just disable them" please?

Comment: delete the not required endpoints and see whether there's any error inside your app, if yes then debug. For example, the `confirm email` feature is related to `EmailConfirmed` field in the dbo.AspNetUsers table, if we don't require this feature, we can delete this field and modify all the models/services/controllers/views related to remove the related codes about this property. So it depends.

Comment: Well in .NET 8 you don't define the auth controller, they already find predefined in the nuget package, don't they? So I'm not sure what should I be deleting

Comment: I'm not very sure about it, I'm based on my knowledge about identity in MVC project.